# Obj-c - Filter array to return dictionaries in which a key contains values listed in NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array (allFriends) which returns a number of dictionaries (data for about 50 people). Each dictionary contains the key 'uid'. I want to filter allFriends so that **all dictionaries** in which uid contains the numbers 1,2,3, or 4 are returned.

How might I accomplish this? The numbers I want to filter with are returned in an array, and are grabbed like so:

```
NSMutableArray *friendUIDs = [self.friendData valueForKey:@"uid"];
```

This returns the data as: `"1, 2, 3, 4"`

No matter what I try however (thought NSPredicate would be the way to go), my code doesn't seem to want to let me filter with multiple values separated by a comma?

```
 NSArray *filteredData = [self.allFriends filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(uid contains[c] %@)", friendUIDs]];
```

Hope I worded this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final predicate should look something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.uid contains[c] %@ OR SELF.uid contains[c] %@", @"1",@"2"];
```

If I understand the question correctly, this should work:

```
NSMutableArray *friendUIDs = [self.friendData valueForKey:@"uid"];
NSMutableString *predicateString = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [friendUIDs count]; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
        [predicateString appendString:@" OR "];
    }
    [predicateString appendFormat:@"SELF.uid contains[c] '%1$@'", friendUIDs[i]];
}

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
NSArray *filteredData = [allFriends filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```